# How to extract network tab contents of Chrome Developer tools via json

Tags: javascript, json, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to extract the network calls of chrome developer tools via selenium webdriver using json, Is there is any other json format available to extract the network size or content-length?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-toools-with-selenium

Comment: As advised tried with the below code http://stackoverflow.com/a/22502405/4683640 but these code doesn't extract the network size..if possible to extract the network size via the above approach pls advice to proceed further

Comment: Maybe this helps you more: http://www.slideshare.net/watsonmw/performance-monitoring-in-a-day/16

Answer (score 4):

You can use the LoggingPreferences to get the Performance logs. It returns the data in json format. Here is a sample java code. Tested this with selenium 2.53, chromedriver 2.20, Chrome 50 on Ubuntu 14.04. This should work on windows also.

```
    DesiredCapabilities d = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
    d.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(d);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    LogEntries les = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE);
    for (LogEntry le : les) {
        System.out.println(le.getMessage());
    }
```

Here is a sample output. It is formatted manually. The actual ouput is in a single line.

```
{
    "message": {
        "method": "Network.requestWillBeSent",
        "params": {
            "documentURL": "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gpwxV4OSKMmR2ASEg6-YCg&gws_rd=ssl",
            "frameId": "31172.2",
            "initiator": {
                "stack": {
                    "callFrames": [
                        {
                            "columnNumber": 11511,
                            "functionName": "",
                            "lineNumber": 55,
                            "scriptId": "50",
                            "url": "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gpwxV4OSKMmR2ASEg6-YCg&gws_rd=ssl"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "script"
            },
            "loaderId": "31172.3",
            "request": {
                "headers": {
                    "Accept": "*/*",
                    "Referer": "https://www.google.co.in/",
                    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
                },
                "initialPriority": "Low",
                "method": "GET",
                "mixedContentType": "none",
                "url": "https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.VTDhrkH4c9U.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,jsa,r,hsm,qsm,j,p,d,csi/am=AJQ0CwoS8fchIGwhrCA1YGBR/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGi2YIjVL5cBzOc1-MD37a1NqZ1jA"
            },
            "requestId": "31172.3",
            "timestamp": 251208.074288,
            "type": "Other",
            "wallTime": 1462869123.92204
        }
    },
    "webview": "8AF4A466-8027-4340-B9E9-CFEBDA769C50"
}
```