# How to extract network tab contents of firefox and IE Developer tools using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, json, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to extract the network calls of firefox and IE developer tools via selenium webdriver using json, Is there is any other json format available to extract the network tab contents

for chrome below link is working
[How to extract network tab contents of Chrome Developer tools via json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219113/how-to-extract-network-tab-contents-of-chrome-developer-tools-via-json/37133568#37133568)