# Accessing web logs via Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium via Java.

I am trying to test third party tracking and I am wondering if there is a way to access the network logs so that I can verify that a specific request came in?

For example, is there a way to access the network tab in the console via selenium webdriver? Also, it doesn't have to be only though selenium. It can be through any other technologies, e.g. a proxy.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-toools-with-selenium) help?