# How to access Chrome's Network panel Cookie tab from Selenium?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to access the Request Coookie data from the Network panel using Selenium ChromeDriver? As explained here [how to access Network panel on google chrome developer tools with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium), it is possible to get an array of all the network requests using the performance API. But the result array doesn't contain the request cookies for each entry in the array. I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve that.

I'm not looking for a way to access the current page's cookies.. I can do that using `webdriver.manage.getCookies()`.. but instead, want to see all the cookies that were sent on each request..