# can I access to network tab of google chrome developer tools with python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to get some information in a request in some web pages and I need some information that can find it from network tab of google chrome developer tools for example when I click on followers on Instagram web, the browser sends a GET method with a parameter named "query_id", I want to find it, I can find it in network tab in google chrome dev tools but now I want to find this parameter with python, how can I do it? is there any way that I access network tab with python?

Comment: Which parameter is it within `Network tab in google chrome dev tools` ? Exactly which parameter do you want to extract?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools There are several shortcuts in this link. Say you have a mac, "Cmd+Opt+i"(Ctrl+Shift+I in Others) will open the tool. "Cmd + ]" (Ctrl + ]) will move move one tab forward. I think you can automate with Selenium to get to Network tab with these two operations. (This is the farthest I can go. Good luck.)

Answer (score 3):

Would a Node.js solution work instead? [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) may help you accomplish this task.

If not, search around for Python libraries that interact with the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). This protocol gives you a lot of low-level information about pages.

Answer (score 2):

I used Selenium to do this. Try logging the performance and find the information you used to find in the network tab.

Check out this answer below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68363046/8491363