# How to access values in the Chrome Devtools network tab using Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, networking, devtools

Is there a way to access values from the Network tab? Like for example everything under the Name column? Im using Selenium and am interested in monitoring the Network tab. Thanks

Comment: What are you interested in monitoring from the _Network_ Tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access Network panel on google chrome developer tools with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68363046/8491363 I did it in Python using Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

In C# I'm using the following way:

Initializing driver:

```
            var perfLogPrefs = new ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences();
        perfLogPrefs.AddTracingCategories(new string[] { "devtools.network", "devtools.timeline" });
        options.PerformanceLoggingPreferences = perfLogPrefs;
        options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.EnableProfiling, true, true);
        options.SetLoggingPreference("performance", LogLevel.All);


        driver = new ChromeDriver(
            ConfigManager.ChromeDriverPath, options);
        ScenarioDefinitions.PathToGoogleCustomProfile = string.Empty;
```

Getting data from the logs:

```
var data = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance");
```

As a result - you would get a huge amount of json files with all the data. 
Translating this code from C# to Python, along with parsing the data you need from json shouldn't be that hard. Hope it helps.

Best Regards,
Vitali.

Comment: Do you have any more details on the above?  I am trying to find the path to specific files that get loaded during the page load and they show in the network tab.  I am curious how to implement the above and what libraries are needed?

Answer (score 0):

I did it in Python using Selenium

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68363046/8491363

The key is setting the performance log.

From Selenium 4.0 onward, the library officially support accessing Chrome devtool info so you can also use that instead.