# How to get data from Response with Python Selenium in DevTools

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Maybe someone knows how to get data from Response in DevTools with Selenium?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ALa.png

I don`t know how to get response data.

Comment: You can get response of XHR by sending appropriate HTTP request directly with `python-requests` and then handle response as JSON

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as this:

```
response = driver.execute_script(javascript)
```

Now `response` has what was returned by the script!

Comment: I am not sure how to get this, and there is a chance that it isn't possible. This is because some of the features of the DevTools interface require being in a DevTools console to run, which Selenium does not allow, and which requires creating a DevTools [extension][https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#creating]

Comment: Another thing you may consider is using MahiMahi [http://mahimahi.mit.edu/] or Polly.js [https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/] to save data from requests. (I know MahiMahi works well with Selenium, as I am currently using it)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is the HTTP response of a specific request happening in the website. Getting performance info is possible [by executing javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium) but you won't be able to get the response of all the requests which is happening in the page, atleast from what I know.

However, if you already know the exact request (or you can get it by [this way](https://www.alexkras.com/copy-any-api-call-as-curl-request-with-chrome-developer-tools/)), you can get the response easily by simulating that request in python. Here is an example -

```
import requests

headers = {
   "your_header_keys" : "your_header_values"
}

data = [
  "your_request_body"
]

response = requests.post('your_url', headers=headers, data=data)
```