# Unable to get Chrome Performance logs in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am using following nuget packages in my solution

1. Selenium.WebDriver - v3.141.0
2. Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver - v79.0.3945.3600

using following code I am creating a Chrome driver instance

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

//Get Performance Logs from Network tab
ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences perfLogPrefs = new ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences();
options.PerformanceLoggingPreferences = perfLogPrefs;
options.SetLoggingPreference("performance", LogLevel.All);
```

(or)

```
ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences perfLogPrefs = new 
ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences();
perfLogPrefs.AddTracingCategories(new string[] { "devtools.timeline" });
options.PerformanceLoggingPreferences = perfLogPrefs;
options.SetLoggingPreference("goog:loggingPrefs", LogLevel.All);
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.EnableProfiling, true, true);
```

and combining with this

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
options.AddArgument("test-type");
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
options.LeaveBrowserRunning = true;

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

but while creating Chrome driver instance, I am getting following error message

**invalid argument: entry 0 of 'firstMatch' is invalid
from invalid argument: perfLoggingPrefs specified, but performance logging was not enabled**

May I know what changes do I need to make please to get the performance logs with latest version of Chrome and Selenium driver

I am able to retrieve Performance Logs using the below code when I was using lower versions of Chrome driver (2.35.0)

```
var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance");

for (int i = 0; i < logs.Count; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(logs[i].Message);
}
```

Comment: Anyone has come across the same issue please and any suggestions to resolve this issue

Comment: Has anyone able to retrieve Performance logs pls with latest version of Selenium Webdriver and Chrome driver?

Answer (score 6):

With Selenium WebDriver (v4.0.0-alpha04) and Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver (v79.0.0) and using the following code, I am able to retrieve the performance logs.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

//Following Logging preference helps in enabling the performance logs
options.SetLoggingPreference("performance", LogLevel.All);

//Based on your need you can change the following options
options.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
options.AddArgument("test-type");
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
options.LeaveBrowserRunning = true;

//Creating Chrome driver instance
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

//Extracting the performance logs
var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance");
for (int i = 0; i < logs.Count; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(logs[i].Message);
}
```

Hope this helps.

All these days, I was using the following two lines with latest versions of Selenium WebDriver and Chrome Driver and couldn't figure out what the issue was and now with the latest versions, the following two lines of code is not required.

```
var perfLogPrefs = new ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences();
options.PerformanceLoggingPreferences = perfLogPrefs;
```

Comment: you are the best )

Comment: Any way to get the Network tab content with version 4? Need to retrieve specific URLs but just for starters trying to see all URLs a particular page loads/accesses when it loads.

Comment: this code works, but you need to have proper Chrome version and related chrome driver