# Is there a way to get the Request Url using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

Hi everyone I am using selenium to enter data into an account, then I would like to get the Request URL so then I can later use the Requests module to fetch the relevant data quickly.

I would like to know how to get the Url in the 2nd red box 'http://.../3361', not the one above it.
How can this be done ?

[image]

Comment: clarification: I am writing in Python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Network panel on google chrome developer tools with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium)