# How to see "Network" tab in selenium? [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a Network tab in DevTools, so how do I see that with selenium?
[image: Network tab image in Chrome]

Thanks

Comment: Try referring this article - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium