# How do I use Selenium 4.0 to print the contents of Chrome Inspect > Network?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[On this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium/68363046#68363046), one user specified that Selenium 4.0 supports accessing: "Chrome devtool network tab information."

My question is simple. Using Selenium 4, how do I print ALL the links under Inspect > Network?

[image: Here is a screenshot.]

Comment: For the love of god man why is this so hard

Comment: The devtools interface is pretty complicated stuff, and it's a sort of constant stream of data.  Nothing simple about it really.   The bi-directional interface stuff (which uses SOCKS) is still in development methinks... but see here for "Bidi" and "CDP" (remote only?) approaches to get at devtools data: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/