# Options for capturing network traffic and inspecting response payload in C# selenium 3.141

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am limited to using selenium 3.141 C# however I would like to inspect network traffic and then programmatically inspect the response payload of a particular network call. What are my options of doing so given my restraints ?

Is this natively possible with selenium 4? Is upgrading my only option ?

I can give more details if need be! Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to write a program to inspect the payload or just debug the traffic of some C# program?

Comment: @PMF I want to write a program that can extract some info from the response payload on a particular network call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Network panel on google chrome developer tools with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401264/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium)

Comment: @GregBurghardt I tried that approach before however it didn't contain the information I needed, I ended up upgrading and leveraging native Selenium 4 features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up upgrading to selenium 4 and leveraging native features to accomplish this